# CiviBooking Development Questions

Tags: civibooking

Is it possible to, or are there plans to, add the following to CiviBooking:

1. Facility to support custom fields on CiviBooking entities such as Resources?
2. Facility to allow partial payments for a resource, with partial payments from different contacts?

Other questions:

3. Does anyone have a concise explanation for what a Resource Configuration is?